# How to center a div?

Tags: css, html, position, center

Before starting to ask, just know that I am a total noob to CSS and started learning it yesterday along with HTML.

I'd like to know how i can center a div with some text in it.
I've tried this:

```
#div1 {position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;}
```

but it doesn't move exactly to the center.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=center+a+div

Comment: #div1 { margin:0 auto; }

Comment: Everybody is telling me that, but it doesn't work for me. It moves to the top left corner.